# Nodejs forked child process exits immediately with status code 8

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, child-process

I'm forking child process and for some odd reason each time the child process exits with the **status code 8**. I did bunch of googling trying to figure out what is status code 8 and what might be causing this strange behavior in Ubuntu but had no luck. I learned that Node.js doesn't even use exit status code 8 so I'm pretty confident that its not the V8. I tried executing the same code on a different but identical Ubuntu server and it worked fine. Just to note, I'm using a load balancer on this server. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Here are the specs :

- Node : v0.10.25
- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 14.04
- LTS Release: 14.04

This is the forked child process (like i said its very minimum)

```
    process.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log('TEST BOT SAYS HELLO ' + process.pid)

        var fs = require('fs')
        fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'abc', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
```

Edit:
There is not other error in the stack trace. Any clues to figure this out would help!

Here is how the child process is launched :

```
        function testChildProcess() {
            console.log('testing child process')
            var testBot = childProcess.fork(require.resolve("./../../bots/testBot"));

            testBot.send({
                data: 'hello'
            });

            testBot.on('exit', function(code, other) {
                console.log('Child process exited with exit code ' + code + ' other ');

            });
            testBot.on('error', function(code) {
                console.log('Child process ERRED with exit code ' + code);
                return nextTracker();
            });
        }
    testChildProcess()
```

Addition : 
The application is ran using 
https://github.com/yyx990803/pod
which uses pm2 to in the background

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2
to launch the application as a daemon.

I tested out spawning child process and spawning a child process works just fine...

child.js

```
    var test = function() {
        console.log('TEST BOT SAYS HELLO ' + process.pid)

        var fs = require('fs')
        fs.writeFile('./message.txt', 'abc', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
        });

    }
    test();
```

parent.js

```
function testChildProcess() {
console.log(process.cwd());

        var ls = childProcess.exec('node '+process.cwd()+'/bots/testBot', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error.stack);
                console.log('Error code: ' + error.code);
                console.log('Signal received: ' + error.signal);
            }
            console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
            console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

        });

        ls.on('exit', function(code) {
            console.log('Child process exited with exit code ' + code);
        });
    }
```

SOLUTION :
Incase someone else gets this issue. I managed to get around by having silent set to true.

```
var testBot = childProcess.fork(require.resolve("./../../bots/testBot"),[],{silent:true});
```

Comment: Probably errno 8: #define ENOEXEC      8  /* Exec format error */

Comment: How are you launching your child process?

Comment: Hey Joe, thank you for any help. I updated the comment with the script I use to launch the child process.

Comment: What are your permissions on `testBot` on the working and non-working servers?

Comment: Joe, out of desperation I done chmod -R 777 ./* on the entire root directory of the application on the working server.  Still getting the mysterious exit status code 8.

Comment: @rastacide, did you resolve your problem? It would be nice if you would share your solution ^)

Comment: @allot I did not manage to resolve the problem. But I did manage to get around by having silent set to true.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

SOLUTION: In case someone else gets this issue, I managed to get around by having `silent` set to true.

```
var testBot = childProcess.fork(require.resolve("./../../bots/testBot"),[],{silent:true});
```